# Firebase auth != null I can write but can't read

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, rules

I have been dealing with the authorization in Firebase for two days now and I can't get it to work. Plenty of reading in the documentation and here in stackoverflow and still don't get it. This is how my rules look like...

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
      "notes": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": "uid"
      }
    }
  }
```

My data looks like this...

```
user-notes-very-upper-root
|_notes
  |_-ugly_id_for_this_record
  | |--date: "Sat Sep 02 2017"
  | |--note: "new note from me"
  | |__uid: "firebase_ugly_id"
  |_-ugly_id_for_this_record
```

Like I said before, I can write but I can't read. I'm utilizing angularjs 1.6.6 for this. I have a firebase `onAuthStateChange` in the `.run` part to listen for authentication changes and I'm able to move arround the app the user obj. My angular code looks like this...

```
angular.module('userNotes').run(function($rootScope, $window) {
  $rootScope.currentUser = null;
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      $rootScope.currentUser = user.uid;
      console.log('User logged in from Run: ', user);
    } else {
      $rootScope.currentUser = null;
      console.warn('User logged out from Run: ', user);
      $window.location.href = '#!/';
    }
  });
});
```

If I change the `.read` and `.write` rules that are right after the `rules` node to `true` I have no problem reading the data but I don't want that. I want to read data for just authenticated users.

How I can tweak the rules to make just authenticated users to read and write data.

#### Update Sept 4, 2017

I change the rules to...

```
{
  "rules": {
    "notes": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": "uid"
    }
  }
}
```

These rules don't fix the problem. I'm able to write but not to read. This is the error in the console...

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"error":"Permission denied"},"status":401
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Understanding Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) documentation (emphasis mine),

> `.read` and `.write` rules cascade, so this ruleset grants read access to any data at path `/foo/` as well as any deeper paths such as `/foo/bar/baz`. **Note that `.read` and `.write` rules shallower in the database override deeper rules**, so read access to `/foo/bar/baz` would still be granted in this example even if a rule at the path `/foo/bar/baz` evaluated to false.

You are not able to read because you have `".read": false`, which overrides the `.read` rule inside `"notes"`. This does not explain though why you are still able to write when you shouldn't be because of `".write": false`.

Anyway, try removing the `".read": false` and `".write": false` so that it does not override the rules under `"notes"`.